# What licencing is needed to distribute tor

Tags: source-code, support

Am I allowed to distribute Tor as part of a bundle.

If so, what licences do I have to distribute with the bundle.

Is there anything else I'd have to consider?

Answer (score 5):

You need to include Tor's license when you distribute it. You can find it [here.](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git?a=blob_plain;hb=HEAD;f=LICENSE)

For more info, check out [Can I Distrubute Tor?](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#DistributingTor) in the Tor Project FAQ.

Comment: That licence seems to be a bunch of versions, which is the correct version? (I'm not sure how to use git)

Comment: @puser Just download & include that LICENSE file when you distribute Tor, don't make any changes to it. If you pull Tor from the Git source, the license is already there, so you don't even have to do anything.